# How to change the cell with selected color when pressing and holding on to the button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I have two buttons on a tableView and the remaining as cells. I have been using backgroundimage view for my cells. like this `

```
 UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_with_arrow.png"]];
            [cell setBackgroundView:img];
            [img release];
```

then i am changing the selected background color as

```
UIView *violetColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
  violetColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = violetColor;
        [violetColor release];
```

everything working fine for me in cells,but in my two cells I have added two buttons. when selecting and holding this button also I need to change my selected background color of the background cell in which that button is added. I was done it but the problem the cell background color is changing only when I am releasing my tap on the button. not when I am holding on to that button.I need to change that also when i am holding on to it. I am doing now like this

```
UIView *contentView = (UIView *)[sender superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

  [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in the button action. But in the cells when I am holding the color changes, not with button why? can anybody help me?

Comment: use UIControlEventTouchUpInside rather than the UIControlEventTouchDownInside for that UIButton

Comment: the above code will work perfectly if you have written the touch event as Rajan said

Comment: i didnt said that it was not working.but the problem is it is not working when i am pressing and holding on to that button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIControlEventTouchDown` event of the button to achieve your requirement instead of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Hope this is helpful to you.